# Necessary Cache Modules in Orchard CMS 1.7

Tags: caching, memcached, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I was going through the caching part in Orchard CMS. The Module: `Output Cache` is already enabled. Should we also enable the `SysCache` module ?

[image]

Also, going through this link: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Caching  it suggests various cache modules to use.

Which of the below Modules should I exactly use and enable in my Orchard CMS ?

- https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/contrib.cache.database
- https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/contrib.cache.memcached
- https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/orchard.caching
- https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/orchard.caching.memcached

Should the `Memcached` module also needs to be used/enabled ?

Our application is an MVC application only and Not related to Azure in any way.

Comment: You only need to enable the ones you need, so it depends on your needs. Maybe your question is where the cache modules are for? (what do they cache?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OutputCache is fine. You onlly need this actually.

SysCache sometimes has shown a strange behaviour some times. Not necessary though.

https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/contrib.cache.database -- It is the ancestor or Output Caching
https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/contrib.cache.memcached -- Never Used
https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/orchard.caching -- It is for Orchard > 1.8
https://bitbucket.org/sebastienros/orchard.caching.memcached -- It is for Orchard > 1.8

Comment: What purpose does SysCache has ?